# React error in project in exporting variable

Tags: reactjs

I am trying [this](https://playcode.io/914190) basic React project in codeplayground, and I am getting different errors based on whether I am signed in, or signed out:

[image]

[image]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has, namely, 2 problems. The first one is the fact that your `src/index.jsx` is looking for a named export `App` from `src/App.jsx`, but there is no such export. It instead has a default export, so it would work if you just removed the curly brackets from `import { App } from './App.jsx'`.

The next thing is that there is no method called `createClass`, but instead there is another package `create-react-class` which provides the same functionality.

The resulting code for `src/App.jsx` would look something like the following (without using class or functional components that is):

```js
import createReactClass from 'create-react-class';
import React from 'react'

const App = createReactClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <h1>Hello React.</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default App;
// Log to console
console.log('Hello console')
```

and for `src/index.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App.jsx'

ReactDOM.createRoot( 
  document.querySelector('#root')
).render(<App />)
```

Edit: [Working example](https://playcode.io/914385)

Answer (score 0):

It is a version problem. React.createClass is deprecated from version 16.0.
Try:

```
const App = () =>  {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <h1>Hello React.</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
};
```

or class example:

```
import React from 'react';

    export default class App extends React.Component {
        render(){
           return(
               <div className='App'>
                 <h1>Hello React.</h1>
                 <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
               </div>  
            )
         }
    }
```

You could use 'create-react-class' package as well.

Comment: Umm, no "render" keyword? How to add inline styles then?

Comment: I updated my answer. For inline styles: style={{ property: "value" }}

Comment: Still getting the same error with your code, you can visit the code playground again where your code is now active.

Comment: Check mine (definitely not self-advertisement)